# git difftool --dir-diff: how to copy back changed files

Tags: git, difftool

I use [git-diffall](https://github.com/thenigan/git-diffall) before, but the author said [it was obsolete](https://github.com/thenigan/git-diffall/issues/24#issuecomment-9503459) by the `git difftool --dir-diff` command.

The command `git difftool --dir-diff` cannot copy back what I change code in the difftool which like [git-diffall's `--copy-back` option do](https://github.com/thenigan/git-diffall/blob/master/git-diffall#L27).

I searched the web, only find this, it seems complex...:

*[[PATCH] difftool --dir-diff: copy back all files matching the working tree](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/PATCH-difftool-dir-diff-copy-back-all-files-matching-the-working-tree-td7587076.html)*

what do you do when you use difftool and made some changes about the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The command git difftool --dir-diff cannot copy back what I change code in the difftool which like git-diffall's --copy-back option do.

Modified files *are* copied back, as long as one of the sides you're diffing is the working tree. That is:

```
git difftool --dir-diff other-commit
```

will show `other-commit` on the left and the modified files in the current working tree on the right. After the tool exits, the files for the right will be copied back to your working tree. (Tested with v1.8.3.2.)

It only makes sense to copy them back when they were originally your working copy: copying files from an arbitrary diff would overwrite your working tree. However, if you want your working tree to be the version from `commit2`, to compare it with `commit1` and to have those changes left in your tree, you could make that clear by checking that version out first:

```
git checkout commit2 -- specific-file
git difftool --dir-diff commit1
```

Comment: well, that's strange, on my pc, it did not copy back, and I just make sure that again! what's your os? windows? I use win7, and msysgit's version is 1.8.3-preview20130601, and use `Beyond Compare` as my difftool.

Comment: I believe the patch you pointed to fixed this, and was merged in [`88f90f8286`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/88f90f8286e9e456ea332e00f87ad39892103544), which was first released in `v1.8.3.2`.

Comment: you are right. After I update to `version 1.9.0-preview20140217`, works great, thanks!